# Tomcat 8 hangs on startup

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to start my Tomcat server on Eclipse but it always hangs on this line on the logs

```
14:44:52.467 INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

I've even set the timeout to 999 seconds and still will timeout.

I'm trying to start my Spring webapp using Maven.

So I may pinpoint the cause of the hang, what is happening during `Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'`? And why is it hanging there?

Here is my context.xml in Tomcat

```
<Resource name="jdbc/default" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="-1" maxIdle="-1" maxWait="-1" autoReconnect="true"
    username="example" password="example" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    spring.datasource.testOnBorrow="true"
    spring.datasource.validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    url="jdbc:mysql://example:1106/example" />

<Resource name="jdbc/default_gathering" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="-1" maxIdle="-1" maxWait="-1" autoReconnect="true"
    username="example" password="example" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    spring.datasource.testOnBorrow="true"
    spring.datasource.validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    url="jdbc:mysql://example:1106/admin" />
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/default</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
            value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes"
            value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="default_gathering" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/default_gathering</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
            value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes"
            value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="defaultDS" jndi-name="jdbc/default"
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="defaultDS_gathering"
    jndi-name="jdbc/default_gathering" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="defaultDS" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="default" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.default.*" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactoryDataGathering"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="defaultDS_gathering" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="default_gathering" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.default.*" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerDataGathering" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryDataGathering" />
</bean>
```

Comment: There is nowhere nearly enough information here to answer your question.  It could be hung waiting for a response from a database that is misconfigured. Show your datasource config and web.xml

Comment: @JimGarrison done. This was all working earlier today just fine then it stopped working randomly.

Comment: The JDBC URLs look suspicious.  A hostname of `example` probably won't resolve, though I would expect the DNS lookup to timeout within 30 seconds or so.  Not sure why it's hanging.

Comment: @JimGarrison `example` is just a placeholder so I don't show my actual url. Also i found out I have a weird network problem today at the office that was confirmed by my network admin. I guess I will delete this in 10 minutes because I found the issue.